# Delete mutiple instances of variable strings within a single cell

Tags: excel, replace, wildcard, excel-2008

If I have a cell looking something like this:

> Ford Escort (ref 1234) , Ford Mondeo (ref 5588) , Suzuki Swift (ref kjgh) , John Holmes (hulubulu)

and want to remove all the parentheses and the information inside those but NOT all the information outside the parentheses. So I end up with:

`Ford Escort , Ford Mondeo , Suzuki Swift , John Holmes`

I found a way to use the MID() function, but this only removes the first parentheses with content `(ref 1234)` and I cannot seem to find a way to loop or repeat this function inside the same cell.

As it's different information in the different parentheses I cannot use SUBSTITUTE, but is there another way to do this in **Mac Excel 2008** ?

Comment: Yes but then I need to know exactly what to find, but as its different info in all the braces (and I have multiple cells), then I cannot predefine whats inside the braces. As I write above the substitute function is not the solution as it requires me to know exactly what to remove...

Comment: `(*)` will remove **all braces containing anything.**

Comment: Not sure I quite follow?
Normally if I would use FIND() I would write something like this:
FIND("(ref 1234)";A1;1)
where the text inside "" is what to find ; then the cell ; then startnum

Comment: Of course - i simply use the Find and Replace function in the menu with * as random character(s) - this works thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Find what: `(*)`, Replace with: nothing.